# Adding JPG Images to folium popup

Tags: python, popup, folium

I try to add an image to folium popup, but failed. I use python 2.7 version, and folium 0.50 version.

Actually, I follow the page mention in other threads, but it still doesn't work

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/ocefpaf/0ec5c93138744e5072847822818b4362

```
import folium

import base64

m = folium.Map(location = [33, -97], zoom_start = 6, tiles = "Mapbox Bright")

encoded = base64.b64encode(open('IMG_1769.JPG', 'rb').read()).decode()

html = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{}">'.format

iframe = folium.IFrame(html(encoded), width=632+20, height=420+20)

popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)

marker = folium.Marker([30,-100], popup=popup).add_to(m)

m.add_child(marker)

m.save("test.html")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you expand on "it doesn't work"? What doesn't work? What did you expect? What happened instead?

Comment: I am following your step and the answer, my map wouldn't even show up.

Comment: also could you explain `html = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{}">'.format`? what is 'format' at the end doing?

Answer (score 2):

```
 import base64
 from folium import IFrame

 #Add Marker
 encoded = base64.b64encode(open('mypict.jpg', 'rb').read())
 html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format
 iframe = IFrame(html(encoded.decode('UTF-8')), width=400, height=350)
 popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=400)

 folium.Marker(location=[43.591545, 39.728056], tooltip=html, popup = popup, 
 icon=folium.Icon(color = 'gray')).add_to(map)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 1):

I've followed [this example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/ocefpaf/20aa2e74e11db30da2ff07c45cd74816) and it (almost) worked for me. Plots were not *base64-decoded* correctly because the `encoded` variable was a byte array instead of a string, thus producing a **`b'iVBOR`** header instead of a **`iVBOR`** header (the `base64` version of the PNG header).

Replacing `html(encoded)` to `html(encoded.decode('UTF-8'))` fixed the problem.

Here is the output.

[image: Folium Heatmap with Graph]

---

And this is the code snippet.

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))
    ax = subdf.plot(x='date', y='temperature', ax=ax, legend=False)
    ax.set_ylabel('Temp (°C)')
    png = '/tmp/temperatures_{}.png'.format(counter)
    fig.savefig(png, dpi=resolution)

    encoded = base64.b64encode(open(png, 'rb').read())



    html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format
    #print(20*'-',encoded.decode('UTF-8'))
    iframe = IFrame(html(encoded.decode('UTF-8')), width=(width*resolution)+20, height=(height*resolution)+20)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)

    icon = folium.Icon(color="red", icon="ok")
    marker = folium.Marker([lat, lon], popup=popup, icon=icon)
    marker.add_to(marker_cluster)
```

Comment: could you explain `html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'.format` why data:image instead your image's name?