# Using Jpeg image in folium popup

Tags: python, jpeg, folium

I want to display a jpg image as the popup in a marker in a folium map. I found some sample code, but when I run it with an image in the same directory, the popup is just blank. The map and marker seem to be created fine, but the popup is just white space.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, can anyone point it out?

```
import folium
import branca
import os

import json
import numpy as np
#import vincent
from folium import IFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy.ma as ma
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_data():
    x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 101)
    sin = np.sin(x)
    cos = np.cos(x)
    cos[20:50] = np.NaN
    return pd.DataFrame(np.asanyarray([sin, cos]).T, columns=  ['sin', 'cos'],   index=x)

df = make_data()
resolution, width, height = 75, 7, 3


station = '42'
lon, lat = -42, -21
mapa = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], zoom_start=5)

encoded = base64.b64encode(open('P8290065.JPG', 'rb').read()).decode()

html = '<img src="data:image/JPG;base64,{}">'.format
iframe = IFrame(html(encoded), width=632+20, height=420+20)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)

icon = folium.Icon(color="blue", icon="ok")
marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat-2, lon+1], popup=popup, icon=icon)
mapa.add_child(marker);


mapa.save("MapImage.html")
```

Comment: i can't reproduce this with the exact same code, no matter the type or size of the image. are you sure the image is valid? maybe it's just white on alpha, so you can't see it?
what does the iframe look like in html?

Comment: You mean when you use that code, you see the image?

Comment: I'm new to Python, maybe this isn't right, but I tried: iframe.save("iframe.html") and iframe.html is just white space. Is that what you mean? The picture isn't just white when I open it up in the windows Photo app. It's also present in the directory where I'm running the code.

Comment: i need to phrase this more carefully: if you open `MapImage.html` and search for the popup, what does it look like?

Comment: The popup is just a blank white space. The popup is being created, but it does not display the image. The icon is created exactly where I intend it. I click on the icon. The popup comes up. The popup is just a blank white space, which is not what the jpg image is.

Comment: As per - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582831/adding-jpg-images-to-folium-popup - try changing `IFrame(html(encoded), width=632+20, height=420+20)` to `Frame(html(encoded.decode('UTF-8')), width=(width*resolution)+20, height=(height*resolution)+20)`. That worked for me when I tested this with a random png from the web, but can't seem to get it to work with one of my own pngs/jpgs. Any thoughts?

Comment: I used Frame(html(encoded.decode('UTF-8')), width=(width*resolution)+20, height=(height*resolution)+20) and got the message 'Frame' is not defined. I changed 'Frame' to 'IFrame' and got the message 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode''

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Should be a matter of the image size. Try with:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(imagename)
image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(resize_path + imagename, 'jpg', quality=100)
```

...

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(open('P8290065.JPG', 'rb').read())
html = '<img src="data:image/JPG;base64,{}">'.format
iframe = IFrame(html(encoded.decode("UTF-8")), width=632+20, height=420+20)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)
```

This worked for me. Note that I removed encoded from the first line and added

> html(encoded.decode("UTF-8"))

to the html line.